# How to fix error in Sending Email in classic .asp page?

Tags: email, asp-classic, cdonts

Inquiry.asp page call from inquiry.html with method="post"

**Inquiry.asp page code**

```
  <%
        message=""
        message=message & "Name : " & Request.Form("txtName") & vbcrlf
        message=message & "Designation : " & Request.Form("txtDesignation") & vbcrlf
        message=message & "Organization : " & Request.Form("txtOrganization") & vbcrlf
        message=message & "Address : " & Request.Form("txtAddress") & vbcrlf
        message=message & "City : " & Request.Form("txtCity") & vbcrlf 
        message=message & "State : " & Request.Form("txtState") & vbcrlf
        message=message & "Country : " & Request.Form("cmbCountry") & vbcrlf
        message=message & "Phone : " & Request.Form("txtPhone") & vbcrlf
        message=message & "Email : " & Request.Form("txtEmail") & vbcrlf
        message=message & "Fax : " & Request.Form("txtFax") & vbcrlf
        message=message & "Category : " & Request.Form("cmbCategory") & vbcrlf
        message=message & "Query : " & Request.Form("txtQuery") & vbcrlf
        message=message & "Product of Interest : " & Request.Form("txtgpo") & vbcrlf
        message=message & "Product of Interest : " & Request.Form("txtgta") & vbcrlf
        message=message & "Product of Interest : " & Request.Form("txtgpu") & vbcrlf
        message=message & "Product of Interest : " & Request.Form("txtsw") & vbcrlf
        message=message '& "**********************************************************"

         set objmail=server.createobject("CDONTS.NewMail")

         objmail.bodyformat = 0
         objmail.to = "info@ankurscientific.com"

        objmail.To = "abc@gmail.com"
        'objmail.From = Request.Form("txtemail")  
        objmail.From = "info@domain.com"
         objmail.Subject="Enquiry"
         objmail.BodyFormat = 1
         objmail.Body=message
         objmail.Send
         set objmail=nothing

      %>
```

I getting error: '80070003'
/sendmail.asp, line no:xx

Answer (score 0):

This is an explanation and solution to your problem: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238956